# Как лучше реализовать pro-версию приложения?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchases

Сейчас столкнулся с проблемой, как же лучше реализовать обновление приложения до платной версии с набором новых функций? Сейчас приложение залито, и удачно скачивается пользователями, поэтому важно сохранение данных (или импорт) между версиями. Понятно, что для покупки я буду использовать In app version v3, но меня интересует кое-что другое. Я имею два варианта как это сделать.

1. На Google play market будет два приложения, платная и бесплатная версия. Но думаю, что я не смогу залить два приложения с одинаковыми пакетами.
2. Это создать два пакета в проекте. Один для платной, другой для бесплатной (например: com.example.free и сom.example.pro).

Но я не знаю, возможно ли обновить свое уже существующее приложение, так как я уже изменю структуру проекта, и по большому счету, у него будет новый пакет и еще, какой лучше всего механизм использовать для переключения пакетов, после проверки (была ли осуществленна покупка премиум версии).

Answer (score 1):

Вот популярный способ решения проблемы.

Встройте всю функциональность в бесплатную версию. Добавьте пустой пакет "ключ pro". В бесплатной версии проверяйте, установлен ли "ключ pro", и в зависимости от этого меняйте поведение приложения (включайте-отключайте рекламу, ограничивайте функции и т.п.).

Правда возникает нюанс, что теперь у обладателя pro-версии два приложения.

См.:

- [Upgrading free to paid Android apps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10392277).
- [How can I use the paid version of my app as a “key” to the free version?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3062946)

Comment: А если я немного "подправлю" проверку и она всегда будет показывать что этот ключ установлен?

Comment: @BOPOH Каким образом?

Comment: "Каким" - не ко мне ) Тот же гугл советует в своих приложениях открытый ключ "размазывать" по приложению, чтобы достать его было труднее. И проверки на различные in-app\`ы советует делать не в приложении, а на стороннем сервере. Просто так что ли? Я из этого и исхожу.

Comment: @BOPOH это уже вопрос защиты in-app

Comment: @DeKaNszn, так если механизм проверки покупки реализован на клиенте и этот механизм может быть взломан, то почему аналогичным образом нельзя взломать и предлагаемую проверку?

Comment: @BOPOH Вопрос про реализацию покупки в случае "замков для честных людей": как организовать пакеты, как сохранить настройки. Защита от взлома находится в другой плоскости. Кто хочет — всё равно сломает, если покупка по сути сводится к проверке "куплено или нет". Ну невозможно от этого защититься, можно только усложнить взлом.

Comment: Я исхожу из того, что приложение "pro". Т.е. стоит денег. Даже не так, с него ХОТЯТ получить деньги. И если окажется, что бесплатное приложение через 5 минут могут превратить в платное, то может быть стоит это предусмотреть ? Тем более, что вопрос "как лучше". Дыры в безопасности - это "проще", но никак не лучше. Хотя да, я только с in-app сталкивался, про pro-версии не скажу, может других вариантов защиты и нет )

Comment: @BOPOH По-моему, вы сильно преувеличиваете масштабы взломов. Мне легче заплатить $3, чем тратить время даже на самый тривиальный взлом. Это банально не окупается.

Comment: Обычно пользователи заходят на 4pda и качают взломанное приложение. Как по мне проверки должны быть на клиенте и на сервере. К примеру если пользователь купил подписку на что либо, то на клиенте необходимо получить ключ покупки, после этого отправить его на сервер который сделает валидацию этой покупки в Google Play и в ответе сообщит клиенту результат валидации.

Comment: @antslava посмотрите на LuckyPatcher. Это битва щита и меча постоянна

Comment: @BOPOH Защита in-app нужна, но пока что нечего защищать. Человек хочет сделать сначала pro версию, потом может займется защитой, после чего выложит обновление в маркет

Comment: @DeKaNszn для LuckyPatcher нужны root права. Далеко не все пользователи рутят телефоны. Гораздо чаще скачивают крякнутую аппу.